# ImageView from url not show in real device

Tags: java, android, imageview

imageview on emulator is show but in real device is not, i following tutorial from [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)

myjava.java

```
url_get_photo = "http://www.myurl.com/"
String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
int loader = R.drawable.photo_blank;        
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
String image_url = (url_get_photo + key + ".jpg");
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
```

myactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_photo"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp" />
            .......
```

i don't know why. What is going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the values of url_get_photo and  ke ?

Comment: Well i would first check if the `image_url` is legit. Where do you get it from??

Comment: @AawazGyawali `url_get_photo` = http.www.myurl.com/, and `ke` as key input from EditText

Comment: @M090009 i update my code

Comment: Did you check that your Phone is connected to the internet, and can you tell us what is the exact `Url` as in whats the exact url. Checkout @Erik 's answer  below, i also recommend one of those libraries i prefer frescoLib form facebook http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html#_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check the URL of your image and Internet Permission.**

*check your code*

```
    int loader = R.drawable.loader;

    // Imageview to show
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Image url
    String image_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";

    // ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    // whenever you want to load an image from url
    // call DisplayImage function
    // url - image url to load
    // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
    // image - ImageView 
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
```

I recommend you use a library like Picasso, Glide, Fresco, ImageRequest(Volley) that has many features can facilitate you this task.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.tecnologia.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Los-mejores-trucos-para-Android.png").into(yourImageView);

Glide.with(context).load("http://www.tecnologia.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Los-mejores-trucos-para-Android.png").into(yourImageView);
```

do not forget to import the library in your proyect.

**Look this link** http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en